# How are pseudogap phases typically modelled?

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, superconductivity

Cuprate superconductors have a pseudogap phase that is not well-understood. What attempts have been made to understand the pseudogap phase?

Comment: Since it looks like this question hasn't garnered much attention, it may help to add some more detail.